# Como remover da url index.php no Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

Tenho uma aplicação no meu servidor local, segui todos passos para que o index.php fosse removido da url no codeigniter, na minha máquina local funcionou perfeitamente. Sendo assim, coloquei a aplicação na internet, na minha hospedagem e também funcionou perfeitamente quando entro. O problema começou quando coloquei SSL, agora se digito a minha URL, a minha aplicação carrega normalmente e com o certificado SSL identificado e validado, porém aparece o index.php na URL, se eu apago da URL o index.php e aperto ENTER, o site carrega normalmente. A questão é se eu digito a URL e entro, aparece o index.php na URL ou se entro através do link encontrado na pesquisa google. SSL só tenho na minha hospedagem, não tenho na minha máquina local.

Segue a configuração do meu arquivo .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|content|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|documentacao|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Obs.: estou usando em um subdomínio dentro da minha hospedagem.

Espero que possam me ajudar, muito obrigado desde já.

Comment: Nada melhor do que a [documentação](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file)

Comment: Eu olhei tudo na documentação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pessoal graças a solução proposta pelo Igor Cacerez que consegui resolver o problema. Só reforçando, o que levava a ocorrência do problema era o fato de eu ter adicionado ao meu .htaccess duas linhas que fazem com que o navegador usasse https, pois como disse anteriormente, tenho SSL instalado. Me refiro a esse trecho:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

O que fiz para resolver o problema foi simplesmente adicionar no INÍCIO do arquivo o trecho de código proposto pelo Igor. Segue abaixo o antes e o depois do meu arquivo .htaccess.

Antes:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Depois:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Coloque esse código no seu arquivo .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Agora acesse o arquivo config.php e altere as seguintes linhas:

Coloque a url do seu sistema.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://SUA URL';
```

Deixei essa linha exatamente desse jeito:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

E pronto, agora é só criar as suas rotas, e não precisa mais utilizar o index.php